# how to represent chemistry structures in the polyhedral representation?

Tags: materials, objects, import

I am trying to build this polyhedral representation of a class of molecules called "Polyoxometalates" - one of the approaches I tried was using Mercury CCDC to "print 3D" the polyhedral representation that it has however I always run into this error - see attached image 1. Any other software suggestions or guide to directly do this in blender??[image]

Comment: You may want to look at this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zXJKYvuCPYY

Comment: Also  Blender for Scientists - How to Make ANY Molecule in Blender https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zXJKYvuCPYY

Comment: Also https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=blender+molecules